# Finding all pairs that have the product equal to the target number

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

I know there is an exhaustive solution that iterates through every single number, but how to implement the divide and conquer approach?

*With an array of integers without repeated numbers, and a target product integer number, return a set of numbers that include all pairs that have the product equal to the target number.*

```
 def product_pair(num_arr, product):
            """
            :type num_arr: List[int]
            :type product: int
            :rtype: List[int]
            """
        Example 1. Product_pair([3, 5, 9, 10, 23, 53], 20) => []
        Example 2. Product_pair([10, 2, 9, 30, 5, 1], 10) => [10, 2, 5, 1]
```

Comment: must it be *pairs* (i.e., 2 numbers) or can it also be more than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not so sure about divide and conquer, but this will be rather efficient and quite simple:

```
def product_pair(num_arr, product):
    value_set = set(num_arr)
    sol = [n for n in num_arr if product/n in value_set]
    return sol
```

Comment: +1. Fast and simple! There is no need to shoehorn the solution to be a divide and conquer algorithm when the straight forward solution is almost certainly better (unless its for practice/school, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
def f(lst, n):
    lst = list(filter(lambda x: x<=n, lst))  # Note 3
    res = []
    seen = set()
    for i, x in enumerate(lst[:-1]):  # Note 4
        if x in seen:
            continue
        rem = n / x
        if rem in lst[i+1:]:  # Note 1, 2
            seen.add(rem)
            res.extend([x, int(rem)])
    return res
```

which for your examples, produces:

```
print(f([3, 5, 9, 10, 23, 53], 20))  # -> []
print(f([10, 2, 9, 30, 5, 1], 10))  # -> [10, 1, 2, 5]
```

---

**Notes**

1. Optimized membership test; you only look for membership in the slice of the list after the current element. If there was something before, you would have already found it.
2. I am assuming here that your list of candidates only contains integers.
3. You can filter out numbers that are bigger than the target number. Those are impossible to find an integer complementary to.
4. It follows from Note 1 that there cannot be anything you haven't found already when reaching the last number on the list.

**General**

- Duplicates in original list: e.g., having two `4`s would not return a `(4, 4)` result for a target number of `16`.
- This is definitely not the fastest one can do, but it is not too slow either.

Comment: also, your membership test is suboptimal.  Using a dict in place of a remaining list would be O(1) instead of O(n)